# How to recover from transaction replication failure?

Tags: transactional-replication

My transaction replication works such that, to curb data growth, every day articles in publishers are purged but this purging of data is not replicated on to the subscriber. So at any point of time my publisher only has current day's data and my subscriber has archived data. How can I recover from a transaction replication failure? My publisher doesn't have all the data so I can't reinitialize my subscription.

Comment: Is it possible to restore from a backup of subscriber and apply a snapshot on top of it without affecting my archived data?

Answer (score 1):

1)Take a backup of your existing subscriber

2)Restore backup to another location

3)Reinitialize subscription

4)Load data from backup restore into reinitialized database

Going forward I would consider archiving data in another way as to not run into this problem again.